# sumar o restar fechas en java netbeans usando jspinner

Tags: java

aquí de nueva cuenta dando un poco de lata . El tema ahora trata sobre java Netbeans
necesito realizar lo siguiente:
Realizar 2 operaciones (resta) de 2 horas ejemplo:

Hora Inicial: 11:30

Hora Final:   13:00

Resultado :   01:30

El proyecto es orientado a objetos POO a continuacion les dejo las imagenes :

El proyecto es java netbeans cuenta con 2 paquetes:

**BD :** El cual contiene el metodo usar para realizar la operacion.

**horademo :** el cual contiene el jframe ,jlabel y jspinner que seran las interfaces con el usuario

BD:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

horademo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

el boton calcularhoras tiene el siguiente cogido :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que requiero de este programa es que realice lo que mencione al inicio :

Hora Inicial: 11:30

Hora Final:   13:00

Resultado :   01:30 --Esto sera la diferencia entre las 2 horas.

Recien estoy iniciando con java desconozco si lo que e realizado al momento es correcto o si bien hay alguna otra forma de realizar esta operacion es por ello que pido de su apoyo.

Quedo al pendiente de sus comentarios.

Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

He tenido el mismo problema hace tiempo, no poseo el código con el que lo resolví, tampoco puedo escribirlo aquí porque sería demasiado, puedo darte mi usuario de Discord y ayudarte a resolverlo cuando ambos podamos si es que aún lo necesitas. Rub♪kAZ#3858